# make UITableView updates from class of the cells populating it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have used the same nib file to populated a `UITableView`.  There are 2 different functionalities I have built out for these cells.  If you anywhere on the cell other than a small button it runs a function and segues to another page.  However if you click the small button, I want to update the `UITableView` and input a cell below the clicked cell, as a sort of dropdown.  I have the below to successfully run a separate functionality:

```
import UIKit

class ContactCell: UITableViewCell {
    //below are the outlets for the conact cells
    @IBOutlet weak var msgStatus: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contactName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dropDown: UIButton!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        msgStatus.layer.cornerRadius = msgStatus.frame.size.width/2

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    @IBAction func dropDown(_ sender: Any) {
        print("selected drop down")
    }

}
```

Moving forward I need to be able to get the index of the current cell and perform a `UITableView` update from the `UITableViewCell`'s class.  How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Do a search for `uibutton in uitableviewcell swift` ... you'll find plenty of documentation, examples, discussions, etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with delegation. Create a delegate protocol for your ContactCell:

```
protocol ContactCellDelegate {
    func pleaseAddDropdown(to: ContactCell)
}
```

Then set up a delegate parameter for the cell:

```
var delegate: ContactCellDelegate?
```

Then subscribe your table view to the ContactCellDelegate protocol (you will have to subclass if you are using a standard UITableView).  This means you will need to write an implementation of pleaseAddDropdown() for your table view class. When you dequeue a cell make sure the delegate parameter is assigned to your table view.

Now in your implementation of dropdown() you just need to do something like:

```
guard let _ = delegate else { return }

delegate!.pleaseAddDropdown(to: self)
```

Which will send that message up to the table view which can take the appropriate action.

Hope that helps.